# Selecting data from two identical MySQL tables

Tags: mysql

I have two identical MySQL tables with different names. I need to use one query to select from both of the tables, with the ability to 'order by' a date field, pulling data from both tables. The data needs to be able to pulled from both tables and ordering by the date field.

Answer (score 0):

You could use union

```
select * 
from table1
union all 
select * 
from table2
order by my_date_field
```

you can use UNION ALL for select all the rows  or UNION for select only distinct rows